# How to get history log from TFS API between GIT tags

Tags: git, api, tfs, tags

I have Git repositories on TFS server, and using web API I am trying to get a list of commits that happen between two tags. Similar way that you can do with CLI:

```
git log TAG_1..TAG_2
```

but I need this in a web API. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this REST API to get commits between 2 tags:https://www.visualstudio.com/fr-fr/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#between-two-versions

Here is an example:

```
POST http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/049d1cfa-a972-405f-923b-fe84c21474e6/commitsBatch?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "itemVersion": {
    "versionType": "tag",
    "version": "v1.0"
  },
  "compareVersion": {
    "versionType": "tag",
    "version": "v3.0"
  }
}
```

Note: Make sure those commits and tags have already pushed into TFS.